# Laravel Accessor or HasManyThrough or something else?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have four models: `User`, `Product`, `Order`, `OrderItem`

When a `User` adds an item to his cart, it creates a new `Order` and the item becomes a new `OrderItem`.

The tables:

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

products
    id - integer
    name - string

orders
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    paid - boolean

order_items
    order_id - integer
    product_id - integer
    quantity -integer
    price - double
```

Relationships:

```
`Product` hasMany `OrderItem`
`OrderItem` belongsTo `Order`
`OrderItem` belongsTo `Product`
`Order` hasMany `OrderItem`
`User` hasMany `Order`
```

I want to be able to list all `Product` and under each, all the `User`s who bought that `Product` (`Order whereNotNull 'paid'`).
Inversely, I'd like to show a `User` all the `Product`s they have purchased.

I've tried taking it in steps with relationships. I can get `{{ $product->orderItems }}` to work, but not `{{ $product->orderItems->orders }}`

Laravel doesn't allow hasManyThrough relationships with a pivot table, which is essentially what `order_items` is, so that won't work.

Maybe I could do this with an Accessor with a join, but I can't wrap my head around it because I can't really set the relationship.

Maybe a custom Eloquent collection so every time I call `Product` it already has all the paid `User` and every time I call `User` the collection will already have all his `Product`?

Comment: If you have deep relationships my advice is to try this library: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has no native support for a direct relationship.

I've created a package for cases like this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
            User::class,
            ['order_items', Order::class],
            [null, null, 'id'],
            [null, null, 'user_id']
        )->whereNotNull('orders.paid');
    }
}

$users = Product::find($id)->users;
```

Comment: this is a very helpful package, thank you. To take it to the next level, I'm looking to be able to look at a product and see not just the users who have purchased it, but also when, which would be found in the orders table (orders.updated_at). Any advice on how to modify the above or write a new function for that?

Comment: @Jacey Have you seen https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep#intermediate-and-pivot-data?